# Is GL_DEPTH_TEST and GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT needed for 2D?

Tags: java, opengl, render, lwjgl

I don't know what these are but can I go ahead and not clear GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT and disable GL_DEPTH_TEST without it affecting anything being drawn such as a simple 2D quad?

Comment: "2D" OpenGL is just 3D with a given perspective and an axis set to a constant (usually Z to 0) .. how do other flags interact?

Comment: I always clear Color and Depth bits.

Answer (score 1):

You are free to use or not use depth testing, in either 2D or 3D, as appropriate.

Obviously if you do that, you'll be responsible for rendering things in the correct order to ensure everything is rendered correctly. In 2D, that's probably fairly easy.

If you aren't going to use depth at all, then you probably also want to avoid allocating a depth buffer in the first place too. That's the clearest way to tell the underlying implementation that you just don't care about it, and allow it to optimise the drawing appropriately (as well as potentially saving some memory).